# How to check if barcode software is installed and run it (or install it) on iPhone iPad iPod?

Tags: php, ios, barcode

I am writing a web application that will use barcode scanning software.

**The process for Android devices is following:**
I have the element on page: `<a href="intent://scan/?ret=www.mysite.com%2F%7BCODE%7D%2F#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end">`

After click, it is checked if user's device has [Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) installed. If not installed, user is redirected to Google Play and software is downloaded and installed. If installed, the [Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) is opened, user scans the barcode and the results are sent back (callback) to `www.mysamplesite.com/{CODE}/` where `{CODE}` is a barcode content sent via $_GET.
Pretty cool!

**The process for iPod/iPad/iPhone devices is following:**

This would be my question :). How to do the *exact same thing* on iOS devices? Is there any software that has similar capabilities please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I have found a solution (jQuery is not necessary but I use it in my app anyway):

```
<iframe id="ios" width="1" height="1" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>

$('body').on('click', '.scan_button', function() {
    var scan_link = 'p2spro://scan?formats=EAN13,EAN8,UPCE,ITF,CODE39,CODE128,CODE93,STD2OF5,CODABAR,QR&callback=www.mysamplesite.com%2FCODE%2F';
    $('#ios').attr("src", scan_link);

    setTimeout(function() {               
        window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pic2shop-pro-diy-barcode-scanner/id382585125?mt=8";
    }, 1000);    
});
```

The functionality is similar to 'Barcode Scanner' on Android, but unfortunately, 'pic2shop PRO' for iOS is not free. 
Anyway it works.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you will have add [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) in your app to scan or create barcode.

Check how to open app if it exists in Apple Store using [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html). But here scanned or created barcode would not be redirected to your app.